# Debian Release Upgrade

Tags: apt, update

I am wondering how I do a Debian Release upgrade on my Pi? I know I can do an `apt-get dist-upgrade` but this is not a release upgrade.

The debian tool `do-release-upgrade` does not exist on my Pi's Wheezy image. So how do I do a release upgrade to the latest release of Debian for my Pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do-release-upgrade appears to be a Ubuntu command.

The Debian way is apt-get dist-upgrade

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you want to do.

Debian on the Pis is soft-float (rather than the hard float Raspbian).

I use soft-float.

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

My `/etc/os-release` says:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux jessie/sid"

NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"

ID=debian

ANSI_COLOR="1;31"

HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"

SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support/"

BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.debian.org/"
```

I just update using:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get autoremove
```